# Conditional rendering in react native

Tags: react-native

I just started working with React Native only recently and there was a task I couldn't accomplish. 
I want to make a screen with a yes/no question. 
Depending on which one the user chooses, I'll either render a component that I have ready, or just close the screen.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You can also use conditions in the jsx code like

```
render(){
    return myCondition ? <MyFirstComponent/> : <MySecondComponent/>
}
```

or even if their is some nesting you can write

```
    <View>
       {...childrens}
       { myCondition ? <MyFirstComponent/> : <MySecondComponent/>}
    </View>
```

or even if only some view

```
        <View>
           {...childrens}
           { myCondition && <View> </View>}
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do conditional rendering in React Native, you can use if statements:

```
render(){
    if(myCondition){
        return(<MyFirstComponent/>);
    }
    else{
        return(<MySecondComponent/>);
    }
}
```